# How to get kml stream from local machine

Tags: c#, wpf, filestream

I just can't get the streamResource to get a file from my computer.
At first i tried the

```
Application.GetResourceStream
```

But found that i have to use the

```
Application.GetRemoteStream
```

So i tried:

```
Uri uriAdress = new Uri("file:///c:/mapsource/wildlife.kml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
StreamResourceInfo streamResource = Application.GetRemoteStream(uriAdress);
```

But got an exception telling me that the GetRemoteStream expects a relative URI or a pack;//siteoforigin:

I searched around and found that this should be really simple, so my final attempt was:

```
Uri uriAdress = new Uri("pack://siteoforigin:c:/mapsource/wildlife.kml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
StreamResourceInfo streamResource = Application.GetRemoteStream(uriAdress);
```

I got that the URI localpath was ""/mapsource/wildlife.kml", which is wrong, and i got the exception from the StreamResourceInfo:

> "Unsupported URI syntax. Method
>   expects a relative URI or a
>   pack://siteoforigin:,,,/ form of
>   absolute URI"

Anyone got an idea of what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Application.GetResourceStream` is for files that are within the app.

`Application.GetRemoteStream` is for files located on the server where the app was deployed.

Why not use FileStream?

```
FileStream stream = File.Open("c:/mapsource/wildlife.kml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.READ))
```